# How can I better mimic the graphics at earth.nullschool.net?

Tags: graphics, animation

I'd like to be able to better mimic the graphics at [earth.nullschool.net](http://earth.nullschool.net) using *Mathematica* and I'm looking for suggestions for either improving my code or getting directed to some other approach.

Below is code to create an animated gif that shows the `StreamPlot` of `{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}`.

```
(* Set appearance of line segments in stream lines *)
(* Line segment plus blank space length *)
s = 0.25;
(* Number of shifts - larger integer values of k result in smoother transitions *)
k = 5;
(* Ratio of line segment length to blank space length *)
ratio = 20;
(* Maximum number of line seqments expected in a single stream line *)
maxSegments = 20;
(* Number of figures to create: n0 leading with a space and n1 leading with a line segment *)
n0 = k
n1 = k*ratio

delta = s/(n0 + n1) (* Amount of shift for each segment *)
s0 = s n0/(n0 + n1) (* Length of blank space *)
s1 = s n1/(n0 + n1) (* Length of line segment *)

(* Figures with stream lines leading with a line segment *)
g1 = Table[
   StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    StreamScale -> {Flatten[{{j delta, s0}, Table[{s1, s0}, {i, maxSegments}]}], 0, 0.0001},
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   {j, 1, n1}];
(* Figures with stream lines leading with a blank space *)
g0 = Table[
   StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    StreamScale -> {Flatten[{{0, j delta}, Table[{s1, s0}, {i, maxSegments}]}], 0, 0.0001},
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   {j, 1, n0}];
(* Combine figures *)
g = Flatten[{g0, g1}];

(* Export to an animated gif *)
Export["StreamPlot.gif", g]
```

[image: Stream plot]

I suspect I'll need to make a series of random starts for the stream lines to make it look less klunky but if there's another way to go about this, I'd appreciate learning about that.

Comment: Maybe something with http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LineIntegralConvolutionPlot.html Not sure how to animate.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you might be better off creating `Graphics` directly instead of using the StreamPlot style options. In this example I use `StreamPlot` just once and extract the coordinates of the arrows, which I use to create `Line` objects with `VertexColors`. The animation is made by cycling the vertex colors.

```
plot = StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}];

splines = Cases[plot, Arrow[data_] :> BSplineFunction[data], -1];

r = Range[0, 1, 0.05];

cols = Opacity[#, White] & /@ r;

lines[i_] := Map[Line[# /@ r, VertexColors -> RotateRight[cols, i]] &, splines]

frames = Table[
   Graphics[{Thickness[0.005], CapForm["Round"], lines[i]}, Background -> Lighter@Blue], 
   {i, Length@r}];

Export["test.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to add 1) add color based on on the four quadrants, that is, when trajectories start in particular quadrant, they are a unique color? Choose an initial starting point and make that one a different color?

Comment: @Moo, you could change the colors by using different `cols` for each line, but note that the individual lines are rather short, so the colors won't propagate along the whole stream line.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

I would like provide an alternative answer using the method of Simon Woods to extract the contour lines. However, in contrast to his approach I prefer to have them as long as possible. This is achieved by the `StreamScale -> Full` option.

```
nlines = 30;
flist = {-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2};
xmn = -3;
xmx = 3;
ymn = -3;
ymx = 3;
subint = 3;
plot = StreamPlot[flist, {x, xmn, xmx}, {y, ymn, ymx}, 
   StreamScale -> Full, StreamPoints -> nlines];
p2 = DensityPlot[Norm[flist], {x, xmn, xmx}, {y, ymn, ymx}, 
   ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"];
splines = Cases[plot, Arrow[data_] :> BSplineFunction[data], -1];
len = Length[splines];
t0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, len];
frames = Table[
   Show[p2, {Table[
      ParametricPlot[splines[[i]][t], {t, 0, 1}, 
       ColorFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y, u}, 
         Blend[{Opacity[0.0, Black], Opacity[0.0, Black], 
           Opacity[0.1, Red], Lighter[Cyan], White}, 
          Mod[subint (u - k) + t0[[i]], 1]]], Axes -> False], {i, 
       len}]}], {k, 0, 1, 0.01}];
```

[image]

Another example

```
nlines = 20;
flist = {y, -y + x - x^3};
xmn = -2;
xmx = 2;
ymn = -2;
ymx = 2;
subint = 5;
```

[image]

Thus, distinct features of my approach are:

1. Use of `StreamScale -> Full`;
2. Background through `DensityPlot`;
3. Randomization of initial times `t0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, len];`
4. Lines' colours blending, here the number of choices is really limited by your phantasy only.

But what are the differences compared to the original animation? Much larger number of contours in the OP is the major distinction. I guess, MA approach would be only feasible for small maps, for larger ones a compilation might be needed.

Comment: Very nice!  I especially like the randomization of the initial times.